# Deluge client cannot connect to the server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, bittorrent, deluge

I have a deluge daemon (version 2.0.3) running on my home server (Ubuntu 20.04).

The problem is that I am not able to connect to it with my client (v 1.3.15) running on Mac OS:

[image: Connection manager]

It's looks pretty weird to me, as I can connect to the server locally via deluge-console:

[image: Deluge console]

Deluge-web also works fine. So, the local clients are able to see the server.

Let me provide a bit of diagnostic information.

The deluge service:

```
$ systemctl status deluged
● deluged.service - Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/deluged.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-06-11 09:39:17 CEST; 7h ago
   Main PID: 43701 (deluged)
      Tasks: 8 (limit: 9357)
     Memory: 36.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/deluged.service
             └─43701 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/deluged -d

Jun 11 09:39:17 hserver systemd[1]: Started Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon.
```

The port is open and the server listens to it:

```
$ netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58846           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
...
```

Authentification configuration:

```
$ cat .config/deluge/auth
localclient:e0f7d1cc3f9280da0f8b33156b14ba20eaef23d6:10
deluge:deluge:10
```

Remote connection is allowed:

```
$ deluge-console "config allow_remote"
allow_remote: True
```

I would be grateful for any help in investigating the issue. The only thing I can suspect is that my router blocks the traffic on port 58846 (I recently switched to UDM Pro from Ubiquity).

Comment: Are both the client and the server on the same subnet? Does tcpdump on the server show the client's connection attempts (TCP SYN packets)?

Comment: Yes, client and server are on the same subnet. Tcpdump shows nothing. From the other hand, I cannot even press the 'Connect' button.